# What does the phrase "blast your way" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the sentence:

> **Blast your way** through 90's nostalgia and into the 21st century
>   with Mr. X, who is the latest hero to join the list of our game's celebrities.

None of the following meanings given on the Free Dictionary fits the context here:

> v.tr.
>   1. To knock down or shatter by explosion; smash.
>   2. To play or sound loudly: The amplifiers blasted the music.
>   3. a. To cause to move with great force; hurl: The volcanic eruption blasted rock far and wide. b. To make or open by explosion: blast a
>   tunnel through the mountains.
>   4. a. To shoot or destroy by shooting: fighter jets trying to blast each other out of the sky. b. Sports To hit, kick, or shoot (a ball or
>   puck) with great force.
>   5. To have a harmful or destructive effect on: a loss that blasted our hopes of making the playoffs.
>   6. To criticize or attack vigorously: blasted the mayor for hypocrisy.
>   7. To cause to shrivel, wither, or mature imperfectly by blast or blight: crops that were blasted by frost.
>
> v.intr.
>   1. To use or detonate explosives.
>   2. To emit a loud, intense sound; blare: speakers blasting at full volume.
>   3. To discharge a weapon. especially repeatedly; shoot: blasted away at the target.
>   4. To attack someone or something verbally; criticize.
>   5. To move with great speed or power: a motorcycle blasting down the road.
>   6. Electronics To distort sound recording or transmission by overloading a microphone or loudspeaker.
>   7. To wither or shrivel or mature imperfectly.

I am wondering if the above-mentioned phrase refers to the gameplay of the app in which the player drives fast and fearlessly on roads while shooting on enemies and drones. However, I am confused as to how would it relate to nostalgia and the 21st century.

Comment: It's being used figuratively. As per the definitions you quoted, the nostalgia of the 90s is the *target* of your destruction so that you can clear a path to the 21st century. Just like you would blast your way through a bank vault door to get to the money inside. How that relates to the game itself is speculation.

Comment: The image usually being promoted is that you should grab an AR15 or AK47 and attack the object of your disdain like you were a guerilla fighter on a mission.

Comment: I'd advise you to concentrate on v.tr. definition #3, specifically 3a, bearing in mind that the verb "blast" is being used with a direct object of "your way". And, yes, it's being used figuratively.